# Quazi-linear DE $u_{ttxx}=u_{tt}^2$

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

So i have a Cauchy problem based on this equation above:
$$
u_{ttxx}=u_{tt}^2\\
u|_{t=0}=\phi_1(x)\\
u_t|_{t=0}=\phi_2(x)\\
u_{tt}|_{t=0}=\phi_3(x)\\
u_{ttt}|_{t=0}=\phi_4(x)$$

My idea was to substitute $u_{tt}=w$ and solve a non-linear DE $w_{xx}=w^2$. But in this case i would have a non-trivial integral which i don't know how to crack: $\int \sqrt{(C1+\frac{2}{3}w^3)}^{-1}dw=C2+x$.

Maybe there is another way. Also, I've found the characteristics of the base equation: $x-t; \; x+t;\;x$, and $x$ seems to be 'multiple' or 'double' characteristic, but i didn't hear of multiple characteristics ever. But this may help, i suppose.

Thanks.

**upd:** the Professor told me those characteristics i found were all wrong. maybe the correct ones are $x=const$ and $t=const$, both multiple. Anyone ever had business with multiple characteristicss?

Comment: Wolfram alpha can do this integral, but its a non-invertible mess. What's the problem about.